How correctly send a URL in feign client as PathVariable?
I send a request, response contains URL to the next page. I need call this url, if it exist.
`@GetMapping(value = "{nextUri}")
SearchResponse getNextPage(@PathVariable("nextUri") String nextUri);`

But when i try to call this feign client method, i receive an error. My URL contains invalid characters, for example:
Correct url: search?view=full&per_page=10
Incorrect url in logs after call feign client method: search%3Fview%3Dfull%26per_page%3D10
How can i deny replacing that characters: '=', '?', '&'
I'd try using some decoders, encoders, string.replace, but its doesnt help
Error in logs:
FeignException$NotFound: [404 Not Found] during [GET] to [search%3Fview%3Dfull%26per_page%3D10]

Please check this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64705156/disable-special-character-escaping-in-call-from-openfeign-client-boot-2-2-4-to

@FrancescoPoli, unfortunely it doesnt work, i got still the same error from feign client:
FeignException$NotFound: [404 Not Found] during [GET] to [search%3Fview%3Dfull%26per_page%3D10]

does this help FeignClient RequestLine ?

Inspired by this (How can I change the feign URL during the runtime?), you can try to change the signature of the feign client method to:
@GetMapping
SearchResponse getNextPage(URI absoluteNextUri);

And build the absolute URI in the client caller as:
URI absoluteNextUri = URI.create(baseNextUri + nextUri);

where baseNextUri is the prefix that (I suppose) is already put in the annotations of the feign client, just check if you need some slashes / in the middle of concatenation.
In this way, what is stored in the nextUri string will be used by the feign client with no escape changes.
